# show welcome message in Microsoft teams using Microsoft bot framework

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have used below code for showing a welcome message to user.

```
private Activity HandleSystemMessage(Activity message)
        {
            if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData)
            {
                // Implement user deletion here
                // If we handle user deletion, return a real message
            }
            else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
            {
                string replyMessage = string.Empty;
                replyMessage = Responses.Greeting;
                return message.CreateReply(replyMessage);
            }
            else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ContactRelationUpdate)
            {
                // Handle add/remove from contact lists
                // Activity.From + Activity.Action represent what happened
            }
            else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Typing)
            {
                // Handle knowing tha the user is typing
            }
            else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Ping)
            {
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Below method is used to call HandleSystemMessage, if activity type is not message.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
        {
            string reply = "";
            ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
            if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
            {
                    stLuis = await LuisHelper.ParseUserInput(activity.Text);

                    string userResponse = activity.Text.ToLower();

                    switch (stLuis.topScoringIntent.intent)
                    {
                        case "Greetings":
                            reply = Responses.Greeting;
                            break; 

                        case "None":
                            reply = Responses.None;
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }

                if (reply != "")
                    await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(activity.CreateReply(reply));
            }
            else
            {
                var reply1 = HandleSystemMessage(activity);
                if (reply1 != null)
                    await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply1);
            }
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK); 
            return response;
        }
```

This code works with Skype. But when I add same bot in Microsoft teams, it doesn't show a welcome message.

Comment: Can you share the code that is calling HandleSystemMessage? Have you checked the Type property of the activity received by your bot when a user initiates a new conversation with it?

Comment: @SidUppal-MSFT I have added the code that is calling HandleSystemMessage. As you can see now, I am calling HandleSystemMessage, only when activity type is not message.

Comment: Confirming that you are seeing a bug with reliable delivery of conversationUpdate activity-type. We are investigating.

Comment: Do you have a reliable repro of this issue?

Comment: @SidUppal-MSFT Unfortunately I cannot share the exact code with you. But the skeleton is same as I have shared above.

Comment: if you are able to reproduce this issue in every attempt, can you reach out on microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com so we can troubleshoot?

Comment: Did you debug your code through ngrok, and get the message which comes from the bot? if yes, what did you get?

Comment: Just sent the email to suggested dev support email.
We're having exact same issue, except the fact that there's really bot receives no event (no web request comes) when user clicks on "Add bot" button and allows the browser to open Teams with the bot chat opened.
Will keep you in touch ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By now (2016-12-30) MSFT Teams does not send any message at all when you add a bot to "contact list". This is a known limitation and to be addressed in the nearest future, as MSFT guys say.

> In the meantime to get a ConversationUpdate message to the bot, the user will have to first initiate a conversation with the bot.

As a workaround you can handle special text sent from user, like "start", or just the very first incoming message, if your bot is stateful enough.

Comment: Currently I am also handling in same way, i.e. waiting for a special text from user.