# How to show welcome message in Microsoft teams using Microsoft bot framework SDK3 C#

Tags: botframework

According [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40839436/show-welcome-message-in-microsoft-teams-using-microsoft-bot-framework) it seems it's impossible to show welcome messages in Microsoft teams while using  ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate last year..

I wonder whether it is possible now. Any suggestion?

I have tried this but it seems not work.

```
  private Activity HandleSystemMessage(Activity message)
        {
            if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData)
            {
                // Implement user deletion here
                // If we handle user deletion, return a real message
            }
            else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
            {
                // Handle conversation state changes, like members being added and removed
                // Use Activity.MembersAdded and Activity.MembersRemoved and Activity.Action for info
                // Not available in all channels
             if (message.Conversation.IsGroup == true)
                {
                bool addedBot = false;
                Activity newMessage = new Activity();
                string res = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < message.MembersAdded.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (message.MembersAdded[i].Id == message.Recipient.Id)
                    {
                        addedBot = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (message.MembersAdded.Count > 0 && addedBot == false)
                {

                    ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(message.ServiceUrl));
                    Activity reply = message.CreateReply("test");
                    connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);

                }
              }
              else
              {
                    ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(message.ServiceUrl));
                    Activity reply = message.CreateReply("test");
                    connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
                }
            }
            else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ContactRelationUpdate)
            {
                // Handle add/remove from contact lists
                // Activity.From + Activity.Action represent what happened
            }
            else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Typing)
            {
                // Handle knowing tha the user is typing
            }
            //else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Ping)
            //{
            //}

            return null;
        }
```

---

**2018/09/06**

**It works.**

Comment: Have you tried anything to check?

Comment: Yes. I tried. I have uploaded what I have tried

Comment: The easier thing to test is to echo every activity (whatever the type is) in the conversation, outputing for exemple the serialized activity as Text: with this you will ensure what kind of message may be sent by Teams automatically

Comment: It works in these cases. ① A user is add to group chat. ②A new user add  the bot. Do you have any suggestions about sending to existing users when bot is added @NicolasR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code works. But it seems it's impossible to send **other existing users** 1to1 message when bot is added.