# Is it possible to send messages to microsoft team from external channel

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have a MS teams bot . Now, I need to introduce this to users. So, the bot should be able to send messages to set of specific users introducing itself in Microsoft Teams .
I have list of people in database. Now, is it possible to send messages to all of them in teams . If yes, how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [show welcome message in Microsoft teams using Microsoft bot framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40839436/show-welcome-message-in-microsoft-teams-using-microsoft-bot-framework)

Comment: No..the bot should initiate conversation in teams to a user introducing itself .

Comment: @Annabelle79 - Yes, it is possible to send messages to all of them but When do you want to send this message - like when this bot is installed or when the user is added to the particular team/channel or any other event.

Comment: @Abhijit-MSFT  have a database consisting of 5 users,now the bot should send mails to all of them introducing itself in teams.now, the bot admin adds new users everyday to the database, now all of them should be sent messages from bot . I'm introducing the bot to the user who are unaware of it.

Comment: @Abhijit-MSFT Also, the user should not be part of any team or channel in MS teams.

Comment: Are you looking for https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?

Comment: @AllenWu The bot should initiate the conversation without prior interaction to different users.The users are not part of any teams group.

Comment: @Annabelle79 - User need to have the bot installed in order to initiate any conversation. Admin can install bot using [Graph api's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages#proactively-install-your-app-using-graph).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but presumably an Admin could install the app for the users.  At which point the bot should receive a `conversationUpdate` and the bot should be able to message the user in the event handler.

As @Abhijit-MSFT mentioned in comments, here is an example of using Graph to add an App for a user: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/contoso-airlines-teams-sample/blob/283523d45f5ce416111dfc34b8e49728b5012739/project/Models/GraphService.cs#L176

```
        public async Task InstallAppToAllUsers()
        {
            string appid = "f46ad259-0fe5-4f12-872d-c737b174bcb4"; // Adobe

            var graph = GetAuthenticatedClient();
            var users = await graph.Users.Request().Select("id,displayName").GetAsync();
            foreach (User user in users)
            {
                if (user.DisplayName.StartsWith("Megan"))
                {
                    // Check if the app is already installed for that user.
                    // Use $expand to populate the teamsAppDefinition property,
                    // and $filter to search for the one app we care about
                    TeamsAppInstallation[] installs = await HttpGetList<TeamsAppInstallation>(
                        $"/users/{user.Id}/teamwork/installedApps?$expand=teamsAppDefinition&$filter=teamsAppDefinition/teamsAppId eq '{appid}'", 
                        endpoint: graphBetaEndpoint);
                    if (installs.Length == 0)
                    {
                        // install app
                        await HttpPost($"/users/{user.Id}/teamwork/installedApps",
                                new TeamsAppInstallation()
                                {
                                    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>() { ["teamsApp@odata.bind"] = $"{graphBetaEndpoint}/appCatalogs/teamsApps/{appid}" }
                                },
                                endpoint: graphBetaEndpoint);
                        // Bot will get a notification about the new user and the chat thread ID for that user
                    }

                    // If you've forgotten the chat thread ID for that user, you can find it again:
                    var chats = await HttpGetList<Chat>($"/users/{user.Id}/chats?$filter=installedApps/any(a:a/teamsApp/id eq '{appid}')", endpoint: graphBetaEndpoint);
                    string threadId = chats[0].Id;

                    // Wait a little before installing the next app to avoid throttling
                    Thread.Sleep(1000); 
                }
            }
        }
```